# Why is VS Code 1.74 uninstalling extensions on reload?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Despite having my sync on, all my extensions seem to be uninstalled whenever I reopen the application.

I have turned the sync on and off and have also re-installed VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was solved by deleting the .vscode folder in my user dir.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well, with the caveat that it deletes some user config as well. Probably deleting the `.vscode/extensions` would've been enough but now it's too late for me to try.

Comment: Removing the `extensions` folder solved my problem. In my case I am using SSH, so `extensions` was under `.vscode-server` in the remote.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by:

1. Close VS Code if it is open
2. Go to `~/.vscode/extensions`
3. Delete the file `extensions.json`
4. Reopen VS Code and install the missing extensions again. I cannot really say why the problem cleared, but I had just changed my flutter installation so I guess it must have to do with the flutter SDK path which did not point to my new flutter installation. As a result, VS Code was deleting the flutter extension files. Also, this way I did not have to delete the entire `.vscode` file.

Comment: Fixed my issue with the Go extension as well. Just renamed the existing file to `extensions_old.json`

Answer (score 0):

Around the same time that this question post here was posted, there was an issue related to the extensions working (not uninstalled) but not being shown in the Extensions View in the November 2022 release: [extensions view doesn't auto load if is close when startup VSCode #168703](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168703). It was caused by [only renderBody when view is visible/expanded #165187](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/165187), and was fixed in the first recovery build of that version by [Revert "only renderBody when view is visible/expanded (#165187)" #168853](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/168853). The issue may be fixed for you if you install version 1.74.1 of VS Code or higher.

There were a couple of duplicate issue tickets too:

- [version 1.74 #168404](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168404)
- [Installed extensions not visible in sidebar #168409](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168409)
- [Local and Remote Extensions are Disappear After Restarting of VSCode 1.74.0 #168524](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168524)
- [The installed extensions are gone, and the panel is showing empty.
  #168656](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168656)

A similar issue was reported around the same time in [Extension disappears from the installed extensions section after reload/ #170337](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170337), and the cause was found to be that the user had renamed their user home directory, and the `.vscode/extensions.json` was referring to old, now nonexistent paths. The issue was fixed by doing a find and replace to match the new home directory name.