# Change PATH dir to install VSCode

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, path, windows-11

So, i update my hardrive and when i install my OS(w11) my user folder got named wrong, i change my folder path and everyting to set the user folder with the name that i wanted(I changed PATH dirs and everything), but i installed VSCode and nvm before the change, i try to run a venv for python but vscode is searching on a different path for my executable(like {ROOT}\Use\ instead of {ROOT}\User), i thougth that just reinstalling the VSCode will work but when I try to reinstall my computer try to access the old User folder and raise an error, is there a way to change my installation PATH dir? Or did i meesed up changing the name of the folder.
[VSCode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpOoO.png)

I try changing the environment variables but this didn't fix anything

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76864930/11107541